# Do ignition coils on small motors (lawn mowers etc) determine timing?

Tags: timing, ignition-coil

I have a Stihl weed whacker for which I haven't been able to find an appropriate ignition module (coil). I purchased one for a similar model that would fit and now the whacker has spark again, however I can't get it to run. There's no signs of life whatsoever.

So my question is: because this coil isn't designed for this particular model, is it possible that the timing is out due to it being a coil from a different model and it will never run with this coil (referencing that inductors shift the phase of AC systems)?

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to answer this question with any accuracy unless you give us model numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The timing is (usually) set by the position of the coil on the backplate - the fixing holes have slots to allow some movement of when the spark occurs.